# MPI_Comm_spawn_multiple segmentation fault

Tags: segmentation-fault, mpi

I try to run invoke MPI_Comm_spawn_multiple to spawn multiple process, however, there is something interesting. When I spawn 40 child processes, it goes well. When I spawn 80 child processes, it tells me segmentation fault. The problem happens on the condition that you set the 'wdir' in the MPI_Info and the number of spawned child processes is big enough(in my test, it should be larger than 53). I wonder if anyone suffers or knows how to solve the problem. My MPI version is mvapich2-1.8.1.

Below is my code:

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define P_SIZE 80
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    int np[P_SIZE],i;
    int errcodes[P_SIZE];
    MPI_Comm parentcomm, intercomm;
    char *cmds[P_SIZE];
    MPI_Info infos[P_SIZE];

    for(i=0;i<P_SIZE;i++){
    np[i]=1;
        MPI_Info_create(&infos[i]);
    cmds[i]="./spawn_example";
    }
for(i=0;i<10;i++){ MPI_Info_set(infos[i], "hosts", "node1");MPI_Info_set(infos[i], "wdir", "/home");}
for(i=10;i<20;i++){ MPI_Info_set(infos[i], "hosts", "node2");MPI_Info_set(infos[i], "wdir", "/home");}
for(i=20;i<30;i++){ MPI_Info_set(infos[i], "hosts", "node3");MPI_Info_set(infos[i], "wdir", "/home");}
for(i=30;i<40;i++){ MPI_Info_set(infos[i], "hosts", "node4");MPI_Info_set(infos[i], "wdir", "/home");}
for(i=40;i<50;i++){ MPI_Info_set(infos[i], "hosts", "node5");MPI_Info_set(infos[i], "wdir", "/home");}
for(i=50;i<60;i++){ MPI_Info_set(infos[i], "hosts", "node6");MPI_Info_set(infos[i], "wdir", "/home");}
for(i=60;i<70;i++){ MPI_Info_set(infos[i], "hosts", "node7");MPI_Info_set(infos[i], "wdir", "/home");}
for(i=70;i<80;i++){ MPI_Info_set(infos[i], "hosts", "node8");MPI_Info_set(infos[i], "wdir", "/home");}

    MPI_Init( &argc, &argv );
    MPI_Comm_get_parent( &parentcomm );
    if (parentcomm == MPI_COMM_NULL)
    {
        MPI_Comm_spawn_multiple( P_SIZE, cmds, MPI_ARGVS_NULL, np, infos, 0, MPI_COMM_SELF, &intercomm, errcodes );
        printf("I'm the parent.\n"); 
    }
    else
    {
        printf("I'm the spawned.\n");
    }
    fflush(stdout);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are invoking MPI_* functions before MPI_Init -- that is not permitted. The first command must be MPI_Init, or equivalent such as MPI_Init_thread.

Comment: I have tried to put the MPI_Init or MPI_Init_thread before any MPI function invocation, but it still doesn't work and gives the same error "segmentation fault" without any MPI information.

Comment: I don't know why, but it seems working well on mpich2-1.3. Maybe, also well in mpd mode on mvapich.